# Сколько потоков в PHP?

Tags: многопоточность, php, mysql

Допустим, на сайте я обращаюсь к файлу `getip.php`, который ищет новые `ip` по известным адресам сайта (это все дело в цикле). Пока он ищет, никто на сайт не может зайти.

- Это что значит, что пхп однопотоковый?
- А есть языки, в которых много потоков и на которых делают сайты как на php?
- Как реализовать в php много потоков, чтоб таких проблем не было?
- MySQL также работает в один поток?
- Допустим, нам удастся сделать многопоточный php, будет подключение к MySQL многопоточным или одиночным?

Разъясните, пожалуйста, кому не лень.

Comment: @gjhgfddjhgjhg, просто на заголовки страниц по запросу в Google "php многопоточность" смотреть не пробовали?

Answer (score 11):

- `PHP` идеологически является однопоточным интерпретатором, а все попытки добавить в него мультитрединг - это костыли.
- То, что у вас происходит блокировка в момент выполнения запроса - скорее всего, результат неправильной настройки веб-сервера или, возможно, некорректен код самого обработчика запроса.
- См. [**Can PHP serve multiple requests at the same time, or one by one?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7980111/can-php-serve-multiple-requests-at-the-same-time-or-one-by-one)

> Every new call to a PHP script creates a new instance of PHP (usually a new process, in rare cases it's just run under a new thread, but this does not affect your question), and multiple instances run independently of each other.

- Вопрос одновременных подключений на стороне `MySQL,` разумеется, тоже решен. Сложно представить себе базу данных, которая не умеет обслуживать более одного коннекта.

Answer (score 4):

Я так понимаю php внутри однопоточен, а за обработку нескольких пользователей отвечает web-сервер, который для каждого подключения запускает новый процесс.

Comment: Это не совсем так. Новый процесс не запускается для каждого подключения (это было бы очень накладно, т.к. запуск нового процесса весьма дорогая операция), вместо этого при старте сервера параллельно запускаются N'ое количество процессов(т.н. воркеров) которые уже в свою очередь последовательно обрабатывают все запросы.

Некоторые сервера умеют динамически стартовать новые/прибивать лишние воркеры, если текущих слишком много/не хватает для обработки текущих запросов.

Такой алгоритм работы используют apache prefork, fcgi и php_fpm, это порядка 99.9% всех php web-серверов.

Comment: PS. Ситуация у ТС возможна, когда запущен один единственный воркер.

Answer (score 3):

Вот Вам первая ссылка в гугле: [Почти настоящая многопоточность средствами php 5](http://habrahabr.ru/post/75454/)

Answer (score 1):

А как насчет асинхронных сокетов, мультикурла, pnctl(форки) на юниксе, а также мультизапросов к MySQL?

Да, это мне многопоточность, а "многопроцессность" технически, но на конечный результат ИМХО мало влияет.

По поводу наилучшей реализации потоков - [вот](https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads) библиотека phtreads, почитайте, реализуйте.

Но ИМХО для "тру" многопоточности лучше перейти на языки, которые ее поддерживают.

Answer (score 0):

Сколько ж тут понаписали-то...

> Пока он ищет, никто на сайт не может зайти. Это что значит, что пхп однопотоковый?

Это значит, что надо сначала зайти из другого браузера, убедиться, что всё прекрасно работает и умное слово многопоточность здесь вообще не не при чем, а потом пойти и закрыть в своем поисковом скрипте сессию.

Answer (score 0):

Все варианты ответа в вопросе не имею отношения к самому вопросу.

Браузер клиента ждет ответ от  сервера. Ничего более. Поэтому и "подвисает".

Научи страницу сайта обращатся к сервису getip.php через ajax.